# Check if 2 list indexes are the same and output certain result based on it?

Tags: python, list

So I'm trying to program a quiz in python. There should be 15 questions and randomly get 5(without duplicates) of those and ask the user one by one. I will have pre-defined 4 choice answers for each question.

My approach is to get the random 5 out of 15 which is stored in a list and put it into a new list. How can I check if the value of each index of random_questions[0]-[4] is equal to any index questions[14] to get what index of random question is the same as which index from original 15 questions so I can prompt the program to print out same index of answers list. So questions[0] question would have the answers of answers[0] but the user will get random_question[0] which value wont be the same as question[0] because it's randomly chosen. Maybe my approach is wrong so any guidance will be helpful. Thanks

```
print("***WELCOME TO THE RANDOM QUIZ***")

import random
questions = ['What is the capital city of Ireland?', 'What is the capital city of France', 'What is the capital city of Germany', 'What is the capital city of Romania', 'What is the capital city of Russia', 'What is the capital city of Belgium', 'What is the capital city of Switzerland','What is the capital city of Egypt','What is the capital city of Japan','What is the capital city of China','What is the capital city of Taiwan','What is the capital city of Brazil', 'What is the capital city of Argentina','What is the capital city of Bolivia','What is the capital city of Panama',]
num_of_rand_q = 5
#right_q_count = 0

list_of_rand_q = random.sample(questions, num_of_rand_q)
first_rand_q = list_of_rand_q[0]
second_rand_q = list_of_rand_q[1]
third_rand_q = list_of_rand_q[2]
fourth_rand_q = list_of_rand_q[3]
fifth_rand_q = list_of_rand_q[4]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `questions.index(first_rand_q)` to get the index of that question relative to the bank of questions you already defined. Assuming your list of questions directly maps to your list of answers you can then do `answers[the_index_you_just_found]`.
Example:

```
print("***WELCOME TO THE RANDOM QUIZ***")

import random
questions = ['What is the capital city of Ireland?', 'What is the capital city of France', 'What is the capital city of Germany', 'What is the capital city of Romania', 'What is the capital city of Russia', 'What is the capital city of Belgium', 'What is the capital city of Switzerland','What is the capital city of Egypt','What is the capital city of Japan','What is the capital city of China','What is the capital city of Taiwan','What is the capital city of Brazil', 'What is the capital city of Argentina','What is the capital city of Bolivia','What is the capital city of Panama',]
answers = ['']*15 #add answers to your questions here in the same order as the questions
num_of_rand_q = 5

list_of_rand_q = random.sample(questions, num_of_rand_q)
list_of_rand_a = [] #create a list of answers to the 5 random questions
first_rand_q = list_of_rand_q[0]
second_rand_q = list_of_rand_q[1]
third_rand_q = list_of_rand_q[2]
fourth_rand_q = list_of_rand_q[3]
fifth_rand_q = list_of_rand_q[4]

for question in list_of_rand_q:
    q_index = questions.index(question) #get index of question
    list_of_rand_a.append(answers[q_index]) #index of question in original question list should match index in answers list so we use it to get our desired answer
print(list_of_rand_a)
```

Answer (score 0):

The choice of data structure may be better. Instead of storing questions and answers in two separate lists and then, after selecting five random questions, having to mess with some indices, just store *pairs* `(question, answer)` in a list and then select five such *pairs* at random.you can also use a dictionary:

```
data = {
    "What planet is the source of lots of jokes?": "Uranus",
    # question: answer pairs
}

# choose random questions:

q = random.sample(data, 5)

for question in q:
    user_answer = ...
    if user_answer == data[q]:
        print("Yeah!")
```

Comment: I will have a look at this approach too. Thanks for your time to reply!

Answer (score 0):

Store your answers, Do appropriate checks to avoid index out of bound exception and try

```
print("***WELCOME TO THE RANDOM QUIZ***")

import random
questions = ['What is the capital city of Ireland?', 'What is the capital city of France', 'What is the capital city of Germany', 'What is the capital city of Romania', 'What is the capital city of Russia', 'What is the capital city of Belgium', 'What is the capital city of Switzerland','What is the capital city of Egypt','What is the capital city of Japan','What is the capital city of China','What is the capital city of Taiwan','What is the capital city of Brazil', 'What is the capital city of Argentina','What is the capital city of Bolivia','What is the capital city of Panama',]
answers=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O']
num_of_rand_q = 5
#right_q_count = 0

list_of_rand_q = random.sample(questions, num_of_rand_q)
first_rand_q = list_of_rand_q[0]
second_rand_q = list_of_rand_q[1]
third_rand_q = list_of_rand_q[2]
fourth_rand_q = list_of_rand_q[3]
fifth_rand_q = list_of_rand_q[4]

for i in list_of_rand_q:
    print(i,'Answer :',answers[questions.index(i)])
```

Comment: @Adi : No Problems. happy to help